# SWIFT core data load to pickerview

Tags: swift, core-data, uipickerview

It appears to be nowhere found. Ive got Core data and needs them load to picker view. How to do it? I think it needs to work with array[String] and not array[AnyObject].

```html
var myList : Array<String> = []
    
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        
         var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
         var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
         var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Activity")
    
         var results: Array = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        
        //???

        return myList[row]
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        
        itemActivityValue = myList[row]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not make fetch requests in the pickerView delegate/datasources. You only need to do fetch once, and you're storing your data in a view controller, so you should do it in viewDidLoad.
2. The array type is NSManagedObject, not String.
3. You can't dump NSManagedObject into the pickerView rows. NSManagedObjects will likely have your own variables, for instance, a name attribute. In titleForRow, you want to return something like `return myList[row].name`, if you've made a subclassed NSManagedObject.

If not, you'll need to do KVC to grab the value.

Comment: I still don't understand. Don't you have a piece code to demonstrate that?